# How to query mongo collection on multiple strings

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am new to Mongo Db and trying to write to write some queries.

I need to fetch list of products whose brand value is not equal to 'any' or 'none' or contains 'not'.

I have tried something line this but it's not working.

```
var query = { "BarCode": { "$exists": 1,"$not":"any" }};
```

But it is giving few errors. Could someone help me.

Thanks,

Naresh

Comment: Which errors do you get?

Comment: @AndreasSchlapsi, error is something related to '$not'. And as well I am not sure how to include multiple strings in the query to check for inequality. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Use the $ne operator for "not equal" (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/ne/#op._S_ne):

```
var query = { "BarCode": { "$exists": 1, "$ne": "any" }};
```

So the complete query could look like this:

```
var query = { "Barcode": { "$exists": 1, "$nin": [ "any", "none"], "$not": /not/ }}
```

The $nin operator ("not in") selects the documents where the field value is not one of the specified values (see http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/nin/#op._S_nin). The $not operator performs a logical NOT on the regex operator (see http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/regex/#op._S_regex). If the field should not contain the word "not" use a more sophisticated regex. Keep in mind that this query won't use any index since the regex does not start with `^`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How to include both 'any' and 'none' and not contains 'not' in barcode.

Answer (score 1):

Please use this URL which will have mapping from SQL to mongoDB query : http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-comparison/
For your solution this will work. For NOT IN with multiple array use $nin

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE status != "A"  =>  db.users.find({ status: { $ne: "A" } } )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do on Multiple String With RegEx Match, Then use Below Code.

```
$matchStr = array( new MongoRegex('/school/i'), new MongoRegex('/college/i') );

$whereCondition = array(
    'name' => array('$nin' => $matchStr),
    'name' => array('$exists' => 1)
   );

$response = $this->Collection->find($whereCondition);
```

This Code will provide all Output response witch do not have **school** or **college** words. It Is working perfectly for me.